# How can I fetch firebase collection names?( Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

for my app, i want to fetch all collection name at the same time in firebase dataStore.first of all ,i want to create "collection_name" like.

```
const [collectionName, setCollectionName] = useState("");
const [englishWord, setEnglishWord] = useState("");
const [turkishWord, setTurkishWord] = useState("");
const handleSubmit = async () => { await addDoc(collection(db,"collection_name"), {
collectionName: collectionName,
words: {
englishWord: englishWord,
otherWord: otherWord
},
});
setEnglishWord(" ");
setOtherWord(" ");  
};
```

after create more then 1 of collection name, i want to fetch this collection name respectively.
Because ,there are two buttons that has a name called their collection name.And i click ,i want to fetch their subcollection (like a words,englishWords,otherWords).when click the button, props called "collection_name" must go to this function (sendSubCollectionName).And render englishWord and otherWord.

```
const sendSubCollectionName = async (collection_name) => {     
let array = [];     
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, categoryName));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
array.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
});
console.log(array);
setFetchingWords(array);}
```

There is no answer in firebase docs about fetching collection name.
i red all of docs in firebase and no answers.Pls help.

Comment: The client-side SDKs for Firestore (like the one you use in your ReactJS app) do **not** have any way to retrieve the collection names. They assume you *know* the collection names already, either because they're hard-coded or because you store them in some well known place. So likely you'll need to modify your data model so that all collection names are known.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for help,and how to add objects the field without changing old objects, is it possible ,beacuse i can add objects from firebase dashboard?